# vba userform Run time Error 91 object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, userform

An error(object variable or with block variable not set) prompts when I close userform.

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
     TextboxTotal.Text = Worksheets("Data_Base").Range("F2")
 expence.Show
 End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim blankrow As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Data_Base")
  blankrow = Sheets("Data_Base").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Sheets("Data_Base").Cells(blankrow, 1) = Format(TextDate.Value,  "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Sheets("Data_Base").Cells(blankrow, 2) = ComboBox1
    Sheets("Data_Base").Cells(blankrow, 3) = Format(TextPrice.Value, "General number")
    TextboxTotal.Text = Worksheets("Data_Base").Range("F2")
    TextDate.Value = ""
    ComboBox1.Value = ""
    TextPrice.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: at what line are you getting your error ? can you step in with F8 ?

Comment: Also, forgot to ask if the User Form name is expence ? if so you don't need to add the `expense.show` in the `UserForm_Initialize`, but at another routine that calls the this routine.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're having that error upon clicking the "Close" button (the "X" in the upper-right corner), and that `expence` is the name of your userform.

in order to prevent the user closing the userform with the "X" button add the following code in your userform code pane

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        MsgBox "Click the proper button to close the form" '<--| you may want to substitute "proper" with the actual caption of the button you want the user click to exit the userform
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

furthermore you have to properly exit the userform, that can be usually done by:

1. having the *parent* sub load, show and close the userform like follows:

   ```
   Sub main() ' your sub that cals 'expence' userform

       ' ... possible code preceeding 'expence' useform exploitation

       With expence '<--| this loads the Userform and trigger its 'UserForm_Initialize()' event handler, too

           ' ... possible code for some userform controls values initializations not left to 'UserForm_Initialize()'

           .ComboBox1.List = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
           .Show '<--| this actually makes the userform visible in the screen

           ' ... possible code for some userform controls values exploitations not already done in its "farewell" event handler ('CommandButton1_Click()' in this case)
       End With
       Unload expence '<--|  this finally "closes" the userfom


   ' ... possible code following 'expence' useform exploitation

   End Sub
   ```
2. having the useform "farewell" sub just hide the userform itself

   ```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() '<--| thi is tha "farewell" sub, i.e. the one that uses the 'Hide' method of the Userform class to have the user leave the userform
       Dim blankrow As Long '<--| better use "Long" type variables instead of integers and handle row index greater that 32k or so
       Dim ws As Worksheet:  Set ws = Worksheets("Data_Base")

       blankrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       With Me '<--| "me" actually refers to the Useform itself. this way you benefit from 'Intellisense' and have your control names available after typing the "dot" (".")
           ws.Cells(blankrow, 1) = Format(.TextDate.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
           ws.Cells(blankrow, 2) = .ComboBox1
           ws.Cells(blankrow, 3) = Format(.TextPrice.Value, "General number")
           .TextboxTotal.Text = ws.Range("F2")
           .TextDate.Value = ""
           .ComboBox1.Value = ""
           .TextPrice.Value = ""

           .Hide '<--| this just hides the userfom from the screen, leaving its actual "closing" to the caller sub
       End With
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: @SandeepBhatt, did you try this?